# What is smart way to get batched gather?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two matrices, `A` and `B`, with shapes `(n, m, k)` and `(n, m)` respectively. `n` is the batch size, `m` is the amount of data in a batch, and `k` is the feature size.

Each element of `B` is an index less than `m` (specifically `B = torch.randint(high=m, shape=(n,m))`).

I want to implement `[A[i][B[i]] for i in range(n)]` in a smarter way.

Is there a better way in pytorch to implement this without doing for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
a[torch.arange(n)[:, None], b]
```

An example:

```
>>> n, m, k = 3, 2, 5
>>> a = torch.arange(30).view(n, m, k)
>>> b = torch.randint(high=m, size=(n,m))

# first indexer (of shape (n, 1))
>>> torch.arange(n)[:, None]

tensor([[0],
        [1],
        [2]])

# second indexer
>>> b

tensor([[1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 1]])
```

The indexers have the shape `(3, 1)` and `(3, 2)` respectively so they'll be broadcasted to `(3, 2)` to effectively have

```
tensor([[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]])
```

and

```
tensor([[1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 1]])
```

which says: for the first row, take 1st `(k,)` array and put the result and take 0th `(k,)` array and put the result. This fills in a `(m, k)` array in the output which is repeated `n` times for each row,

to get

```
>>> a[torch.arange(n)[:, None], b]

tensor([[[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
         [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4]],

        [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

        [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
         [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])
```

comparing with list comprehension:

```
>>> [a[i][b[i]] for i in range(n)]

[tensor([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]),
 tensor([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]),
 tensor([[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
         [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])]
```